# How to override contact form 7 js files in child theme

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, contact-form-7

I am using contact form 7 plugin in my WordPress website. I have a situation where I have to modify and add the new JavaScript code to extend the functionality. Now I want to override the file `script.js` in my child theme.
File location: `plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js`

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Override script file in your child theme first you need to dequeue your plugin script file using  [wp_dequeue_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script)

After dequeue your plugin script you need to add script file again with child theme path. put your plugin script[`scripts.js`] file in you child theme. Check below example code. put below code in you child theme `function.php` file

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pre_contact_form_callback', 100);
function pre_contact_form_callback()
{
    wp_dequeue_script('contact-form-7');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'contact-form-7-child', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/scripts.js', array( 'jquery', 'jquery-form' ), null, true);
}
```

Comment: @Anilsharma this answer is helpful or not ?

Comment: It helped. Thankyou for saving my day!